# Javascript Dropdown Objects Only Toggling First Dropdown

Tags: javascript, php

I created a set of dropdown items using Javascript, PHP, CSS, and HTML. The goal of the page is to give more information in dropdown style. It pulls data from a MySQL database and uses a PHP while loop to create multiple dropdown items. However, when I click on any dropdown, it only toggles the first dropdown and not the targetted one.

HTML:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
header('Location: AdminLogin.php');
exit;
}
$user = 'root';
$password = 'hidden';
$db = 'Internships';
$host = 'localhost';

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Internships</title>
    <link href="UserStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropdown.css">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="BT-Square-Logo.png" class="logo" alt='BT Logo'>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
            <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='Pre-approved_Internships.php'>Pre-approved Internships</a></li>
            <li><a href='Logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
    <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Internships");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
    ?>
    <div class="demo">
      <div class="head" onclick="toggleActive(); return false;"><?= $row['Company'] ?>
      </div>
      <div class="content-outer hidden">
        <div class="content-inner">
                <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <th>Cluster</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Fax</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Skills</th>
                <th>Tasks</th>
                <th>Hours</th>
                <th>Number of Students</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?= $row['Cluster']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['Company']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['FName']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['LName']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['Address1'] . ', ' . $row['Address2'] . ', ' . $row['City'] . ', ' . $row['State'] . ', ' . $row['Zipcode']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['Phone']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['Fax']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['Email']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['Description']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['Skill1'] . ', ' . $row['Skill2'] . ', ' . $row['Skill3'] . ', ' . $row['Skill4'] . ', ' . $row['Skill5'];?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['Task1'] . ', ' . $row['Task2'] . ', ' . $row['Task3'] . ', ' . $row['Task4'] . ', ' . $row['Task5']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['Hours']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['Students'] ?></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <script  src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const content = document.querySelector('.content-outer')

function toggleActive () {
  content.classList.toggle('hidden')
}
```

Comment: Immediately, the `querySelector()` only pulls the first element it finds -- you would want to use `querySelectorAll()` and loop through the node list you get back. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using Javascript. If you could help me with the syntax, it would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `querySelector` to select the first element in the DOM. For this to work, you need to have a unique ID for every element. If you have a column named `id` or something like that containing a unique id, you can use that.

Change this

`<div class="head" onclick="toggleActive(); return false;">`

Into this

`<div class="head" onclick="toggleActive("<?= $row['id']; ?>"); return false;">`

And this

`<div class="content-outer hidden">`

Into this

`<div id="content-<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="content-outer hidden">`

And the javascript would be

```
function toggleActive (id) {
  document.getElementById("content-"+id).classList.toggle('hidden')
}
```

You are essentially giving a unique identifier to your elements, so you can access them through Javascript.

If you don't have an `id`, you can use a counter inside the `while`.